# Cloning group in konvajs

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

I want to clone a group from one layer to another layer. But when I try to get the parent layer of the newly created (cloned) group, no parent is set.

```
let group1 = layer1.findOne('.group1')

layer2.add(group1.clone())

layer2.findOne('.group1').getParent() // returns null
```

Comment: Try moveto https://konvajs.org/docs/groups_and_layers/Change_Containers.html.

Comment: Can you make a demo? I just tried this: https://jsbin.com/rumobexawi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

It works just fine.